# Why the symbols are not equals at their size?

Tags: koma-script, parts

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.1-1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}

\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

\setkomafont{part}{\itshape\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{partnumber}{\fontsize{26pt}{26pt}\selectfont}
\renewcommand\partheadmidvskip{}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{Part~ :\thepart~~}

\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{\hfill\underline{{\adforn{36}#2#3\adforn{64}}}\hfill}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}

\part{ABCD}

\section{abcd}
\end{document}
```

I know the picture is at Hebrew. but I change the MWE to English :)
How can I make that the both `adforn` symbols will be size equals?

Thakn you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add a `\usekomafont{part}` for the `\adforn{36}`:

```
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \hfill
  \underline{\usekomafont{part}\adforn{36}#2#3\adforn{64}}
  \hfill
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Explanation: `#3` is the preformated part title including the font settings for element `part` which affects the second adforn symbol. To demonstrate this you can group `#2#3`:

```
\renewcommand\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  \hfill
  \underline{\adforn{36}{#2#3}\adforn{64}}% #2#3 in an additional group
  \hfill
}
```

Result:

[image]